# Tool to view memory as bitmap?

Tags: video, debugging, pixel-graphics

I do a bit of raster graphics and video programming. What would be super handy would be some **IDE**, **plugin**, **debugger** or **tool** that is able to **view a chunk of memory as a bitmap image**.

Most debuggers let you introspect composite types, arrays, strings and so on. When it comes to bitmaps though, they can only show you the raw memory, and since I'm not a hacker from the Matrix, it's very hard to diagnose problems here.

It would be great if there were some tool that, given a memory location, pixel format (e.g. ARGB8888, YUV420) and image dimensions, show a picture of what that memory represents. What I currently have to do is write code to dump the memory out to file and view it in an external viewer, which is very clunky.

Requirements:

- Any of Windows (XP or greater), OS X or Linux
- Must work with program memory or integrated in IDE; must not be file-only viewer
- If IDE, support latest C/C++ standards (C99 and greater, C++11 and greater), must not require custom language, platform or types
- Choose from a number of pixel formats
- Any price is ok

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this, because you did not get other answers for more than a year now. I'd say your request is quite specific.

### Pictures in dumps

If you have a Windows crash dump (.dmp) file, you can open it in [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is the free Microsoft debugger for user mode and kernel mode dumps.

There are 4 undocumented commands that can find images in memory. Those commands are part of the *ext* extension which is loaded by default:

```
!findgifs
!findjpegs
!findjpgs
!findpngs
```

The output will give you the start and end address of an image in memory. You can use that to write the image to disk using the `.writemem` command.

Example output of a running Notepad++ application:

```
0:000> |
.  0    id: 472c    attach  name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
0:000> !findpngs
Found:  0062387c    00636f76
Found:  06ed3cfa    07940c87
...
0:000> .writemem c:\tmp\writemem.png 0062387c 00636f76
Writing 136fb bytes............
```

The result was this PNG file:

[image: PNG file extracted from Notepad++]

You can automate this with [PyKD](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) to write all PNGs from memory to disk. You'll need the [`dbgCommand()`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#dbgCommand) function to do `!findpngs` first, then process the string (split the lines and extract start and end address) and then use `dbgCommand()` again to do the `.writemem`. Unfortunately I don't have it installed at the moment, so I can't provide a complete script.

Why I consider this as an answer:

> Any of Windows (XP or greater)

WinDbg is available for Windows XP through 10. Maybe you need [different versions of WinDbg](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/), but they should still be available.

> Must work with program memory or integrated in IDE; must not be file-only viewer

This solution works from memory (crash dump file) with the workaround over disk. This may not be 100% what you want, but perhaps it's still easier to do (if scripted) than from any other IDE.

> Choose from a number of pixel formats

Actually I'm not sure how it detects that. IMHO there's no way to explicitly define a pixel format.

> Any price is ok

WinDbg and PyKD are both available gratis.

### Dump2Picture

Reading your question the first time I thought you'd be looking for something like this. I'll leave this as a reference for other readers, if that's what they want.

The tool [Dump2Picture](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/memory-dump-live-memory-visualization) can convert a Windows crash dump (.dmp) into a picture. The author [of these books](http://www.patterndiagnostics.com/index.php?q=publications) has used it as a design element at the top of the book cover.

However, you'll hardly find real images (such as JPGs) in there. The reasons are:

- the pixels will not be aligned correctly, i.e. the width and height of the generated picture don't match the image in memory
- the color depth will likely not match